# Working with a percentage-based column system — dealing with decimals?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a responsive column system for my site. Essentially, a block of images in a grid, that will look similar to this in the end:

[image]

Where the black lines represent the container, and the colours represent an assortment of images.

The problem is, this layout would require a 6-column grid with 0 gutter. Working with percentages, each column would need to be 16.66% repeating, which would be difficult to keep accurate. What is the best way to deal with creating something like this? The only way I would know of is using CSS to set widths to percentages, but, like I said, that would be difficult to keep accurate with decimal places and all.

Comment: I think bootstrap framework keeps 4 decimal places and rounds the last number.

Comment: Masonry framework may be a good example to refer to to see how they handle it...

Answer (score 0):

If I was producing exactly that layout with static HTML, I'd have classes for multiples of width 16.6% and just round up the rightmost div for each row to make up the 100% (E.g 5x16.6% and 1x17%).  Sounds messy but you could do it quite cleanly with Class attributes like "two-col right" etc.

Personally my OCD would force me to rethink the number of columns  or add a gutter to make everything add up cleanly.  Also, if you are happy to provide javascript dependent pages, this is a fantastic (already responsive) jQuery plugin for this type of layout http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/index.html.